# Getting the error "does not have a Release file."

Tags: 18.04, repository

I keep getting the error:

> E: The repository 'http://apt.llvm.org/bionic bionic Release' does not
>   have a Release file.

when I try to install llvm. At the bottom of the source file (`/etc/apt/sources.list`), it is (what I think should be) the repository

> ...
>   deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-9 main

I'm not sure if it hasn't been sourced correctly or if it's missing anything. Any suggestion would be welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: What is the output of `grep "apt.llvm" /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`?

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ bionic llvm-toolchain-bionic-10 main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-9 main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-9 main
/etc/apt/sources.list:# deb-src http://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-9 main

Comment: The repository information in /etc/apt/sources.list is wrong. It contains extra bionic.

Comment: I'm unable to clean up this mess so I'm going to restart the process from square one understanding (more or less) what went wrong earlier.

Comment: The repository in sources.list should look like `deb https://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ llvm-toolchain-bionic-10 main` instead of `deb https://apt.llvm.org/bionic/ bionic llvm-toolchain-bionic-10 main`. Tip: Never add 3rd party repositories in sources.list. Instead put them in something.list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: I was finally able to complete a successful installation. I was just following the instructions, which indicate to run `sudo bash -c "$(wget -O - https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh)" ` that modifies the source file. There's probably some way to modify the command in order to achieve what you're suggesting but I'm just not familiar with it. Thanks.